# CentOS Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

Please how do I make sure that my i.p IP address have separate content than my domains.

Anytime I visit my i.p address it keeps showing me the first entry in my virtual host file.

Comment: Are you locating it by IP or by hostname?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this from the server or the client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any command line web browser such as: `curl`, `links`, `lynx`, ... to browse to your IP address and pass the extra header, something like this:

```
# curl IP.address -H "Host:your.domain"
```